# Convert the first bit of the hash the locale name to plain text i.e. en_GB to Great Britain in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

I have this hash and the first part of it i need to convert to plain text for example  en_GB 
would be Great Britain. This is an example response i get from the Facebook api.

```
    {"en_GB"=>6836, "en_US"=>3414, "it_IT"=>120, "es_LA"=>37, "fr_FR"=>24, "zh_TW"=>18, "pt_BR"=>18, "de_DE"=>16, "hr_HR"=>15, "pl_PL"=>12, "es_ES"=>12, "ru_RU"=>10, "id_ID"=>9, "el_GR"=>8, "ar_AR"=>8, "th_TH"=>8, "tr_TR"=>8, "bg_BG"=>7, "lv_LV"=>6, "zh_CN"=>6, "cs_CZ"=>5, "ro_RO"=>4, "pt_PT"=>4, "en_PI"=>4, "he_IL"=>3, "sk_SK"=>3, "hu_HU"=>3, "mk_MK"=>3, "nl_NL"=>2, "sv_SE"=>2, "zh_HK"=>2, "lt_LT"=>2, "nl_BE"=>2, "fb_LT"=>1, "en_IN"=>1, "sl_SI"=>1, "sq_AL"=>1, "ko_KR"=>1, "da_DK"=>1, "ka_GE"=>1, "cy_GB"=>1, "mr_IN"=>1, "sr_RS"=>1, "nb_NO"=>1}
```

Does anybody know how to convert it to plain text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the locale data in  `/config/locales/en.yml` in your rails application as

```
en:
  en_GB: "Great Britain"
  en_US: 'United States'
  ..so on..
```

Then

```
fb_response = {"en_GB"=>6836, "en_US"=>3414, "it_IT"=>120, "es_LA"=>37, "fr_FR"=>24, "zh_TW"=>18, "pt_BR"=>18, "de_DE"=>16, "hr_HR"=>15, "pl_PL"=>12, "es_ES"=>12, "ru_RU"=>10, "id_ID"=>9, "el_GR"=>8, "ar_AR"=>8, "th_TH"=>8, "tr_TR"=>8, "bg_BG"=>7, "lv_LV"=>6, "zh_CN"=>6, "cs_CZ"=>5, "ro_RO"=>4, "pt_PT"=>4, "en_PI"=>4, "he_IL"=>3, "sk_SK"=>3, "hu_HU"=>3, "mk_MK"=>3, "nl_NL"=>2, "sv_SE"=>2, "zh_HK"=>2, "lt_LT"=>2, "nl_BE"=>2, "fb_LT"=>1, "en_IN"=>1, "sl_SI"=>1, "sq_AL"=>1, "ko_KR"=>1, "da_DK"=>1, "ka_GE"=>1, "cy_GB"=>1, "mr_IN"=>1, "sr_RS"=>1, "nb_NO"=>1}

fb_response = Hash[fb_response.map {|k, v| [t(k.to_sym), v] }]
```

`map` returns new array with the results of running block once for every element and Hash[] creates a new hash with each [k, v] pair in the array returned. In the block we are converting the key to symbol and passing it to the `#translate` aliased as `t`, that will translate it to current locale.